# Get unique values for each column with LIMIT query using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table in the following format in PostgreSQL:

```
Name    Age Gender  Occupation
John    32  Male    Software Engineer
Sarah   26  Female  Graphic Designer
David   41  Male    Sales Manager
Emily   29  Female  Marketing Coordinator
Michael 37  Male    Project Manager
```

I would like to get all unique values from each column for the query result when also using limit. Is this achievable in postgresql?

So for example my query would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE Gender = 'Male'
LIMIT 2;
```

I expect to get all unique values per column regardless of my limit:

```
Name: John, David, Michael
Age: 32, 41, 37
Occupation: Software Engineer, Sales Manager, Project Manager
Gender: Male
```

How can I do that using SQL?

Comment: Presentation is usually done in the presentation layer, not in the database layer. You could however use the extension tablefunc and use the function crosstab to create the presentation.

Comment: Hmm I agree but how can I get the correct values, so that I can pass them to presentation layer?

Comment: It's unclear to me what result you expect. You have a `limit 2` that only display two rows. But your expected output is a transposed representation of the table where each column makes up a row that contains a comma separated string. But this display has more than two rows and more than two values per row, so it's totally unclear to me how the limit and your expected output match together

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using `string_agg`. You may use another aggregation function if more relevant.

```sql
select
    string_agg(distinct "name", ',') "names",
    string_agg(distinct age::text, ',') ages,
    string_agg(distinct gender, ',') genders,
    string_agg(distinct occupation, ',') occupations
from the_table;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6sHNNyJ8doTNPQCt6m3fxm/0).

Unrelated but it is not a good idea to keep age in a table because it keeps changing. Better have the date of birth and calculate the age using [age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries, to completely disregard outer where clause:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT STRING_AGG (distinct Name,', ') FROM my_table) Name,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG (distinct Age,', ') FROM my_table) Age,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG (distinct Occupation,', ') FROM my_table) Occupation,
    gender
FROM
    my_table
WHERE 
    Gender = 'Male'
LIMIT 2;
```

**EDIT:** To disregard only `LIMIT` you could use CTE.

```sql
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE Gender = 'Male'
)
SELECT
    (SELECT STRING_AGG (distinct Name,', ') FROM t) Name,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG (distinct Age,', ') FROM t) Age,
    (SELECT STRING_AGG (distinct Occupation,', ') FROM t) Occupation,
    gender
FROM  
    t
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: But if I disregard where clause then the distinct will run on whole table, what I am looking for is a way to disregard LIMIT and get unique values after WHERE clause filtered out the data

Comment: @AlexT, added option to disregard only the limit part to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the unique values for each column with the Limit,

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM my_table LIMIT 1) AS name,
  (SELECT DISTINCT age FROM my_table LIMIT 1,1) AS age,
  (SELECT DISTINCT occupation FROM my_table LIMIT 2,1) AS occupation,
  ...
FROM my_table
LIMIT 1
```

This query selects the distinct values for each column using subqueries with the `DISTINCT` keyword and assigns them to separate column aliases (column_1, column_2, column_3, etc.). The `LIMIT` keyword is used to specify the number of unique values to select for each column.

`Note` that this query assumes that all columns in the table have the same data type. If columns have different data types.

Additionally, this query may not be efficient for tables with a large number of columns or a large number of distinct values.